# Change Graylog UI

Tags: graylog2

I have just setup Graylog server, but I want to change something about the login screen in the web interface. Is it possible to change the UI for graylog-web?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot modify the UI from your installation. You need to make your changes in the [server source](https://github.com/Graylog2/graylog2-server) and then recompile it.

For example, if you want to change the login page, you would customize the file [LoginPage.jsx](https://github.com/Graylog2/graylog2-server/blob/master/graylog2-web-interface/src/pages/LoginPage.jsx).